# How to run Java application in KDE with Qt-like UI?

Tags: kubuntu, java, kde, gtk, qt

Continuing my question in [Install Ubuntu or Kubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6800/install-ubuntu-or-kubuntu)

I have tried Kubuntu (KDE), and it was very cool as cool as Ubuntu (GNOME). but there is little problem with its user interface when we start Java application (LimeWire, Netbeans, Eclipse). User interface changed to Metal, (which I think is a bit old school).

Can we run it with Qt like UI?, such as when we start Java application in Gnome (run with GTK like UI/emulation GTK like UI)?

I hear there is a class for Java in order to make Java application UI like Qt, called the Qt/Jambi bindings for Java. How can we integrate it in KDE when we start Java application?

My other question is if not wrong, OpenOffice was built in Java,so why OpenOffice can run with Qt like UI in KDE?

Comment: OpenOffice is not built in java, some underlying functionality uses java.

Comment: What have you configured in system-settings-> application appearance under GTK appearance?

Comment: hmm, I already did it, but the java application is still using GTK like UI instead of QT like UI.

Comment: Similar question for GTK: http://askubuntu.com/questions/21886/how-can-i-get-a-java-apps-to-use-the-gtk-theme

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162571/is-there-a-way-to-specify-a-global-look-and-feel-for-swing-apps

Comment: From my experiences, Swing does not use any GUI theme unless when you are running a Gnome 3 based desktop environment (Gnome Shell or Cinnamon). I don't know why though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using those Qt bindings is no solution (it requires that the whole application's GUI has to be rewritten).

And OpenOffice.org is written in C++ mostly, with some parts written in other languages like Java.  It also has its own GUI toolkit that can mimic Gtk or Qt (partially) using themes.

And if there is no Qt or KDE-like theming included, I have no idea how to make one.  (I just saw that there are a couple of additional Swing themes in the repository, that might be a thing to try out for those applications that use Swing.)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use some sort of aesthetically Qt-compatible GTK theme, through the java GTK Style look and feel.

In Kubuntu, for GTK applications you can install the Qt Curve theme (**qtcurve** package), you should then be able to configure the default GTK style in KDE System Settings (you will need the **kde-config-gtk** package).

You should then be able to set the GTK look and feel in java applications. You can easily test it with this [Java Web Start application](http://web.archive.org/web/20070205162314/http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/jws/SwingSet2.jnlp).

Comment: The link is broken as of the time this comment is posted.

Answer (score 0):

Install `gtk3-engines-oxygen` for `Gtk3` and `gtk2-engines-qtcurve` for `Gtk2`, and switch to theme in `System Settings > Application Appearance > Gtk Configuration`.

If you don't have a `Gtk Configuration`, install `kde-config-gtk`. It's also recommended to install whole `qtcurve` packages and use it.