# How can I get a java apps to use the GTK+ theme?

Tags: java, themes, gtk, application-development

Is there a way to get java apps to use my gtk theme?

Comment: Similar question for KDE/Qt: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6948/how-to-run-java-application-in-kde-with-qt-like-ui

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162571/is-there-a-way-to-specify-a-global-look-and-feel-for-swing-apps

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can try to set Java's default look and feel to GTK:

Open a terminal ( Ctrl + Alt + T )  and paste  the upper one for openjdk and the lower one for sun java .

`gksu gedit /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/swing.properties`

`gksu gedit /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/lib/swing.properties`

- Follow the comment in that file and remove the hash sign, so it looks like:

  ```
  # uncomment to set the default look and feel to GTK
  swing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel
  ```
- Save and restart the java app.

Before and after:

[image]

Comment: didn't fix it, but still very useful for me :) thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I used this as a tip but instead did; ```UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel");``` which does not require any configuration file editing.

Comment: @RolandiXor If this didn't work, that means the developer of the app hardcoded the look and feel. Nothing you can do about that, unless it is open-source. :(

Comment: It hepled me to solve "jdk bold font" bug. Thank you.

Comment: Didn't fix for universalmediaserver on Ubuntu Mate 14.

Comment: No dice on Ubuntu Mate, not even with OpenJDK Java 8 Policy Tool, which I don't believe it's hardcoded...

Comment: swing.properties file seems to be ignored (open-jdk 8 & openjdk-11) even if you put swing.crossplatformlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel in it (which seems to be the correct variable to set).

Setting _JAVA_OPTIONS in your environment (see below) seems more promising

Answer (score 16):

If you have already tried the above solutions - try using this (helped me on Xfce):

1. `export _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel -Dswing.crossplatformlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel'`
2. Then launch in this terminal your app.
3. If you are satisfied with your result - add this line to your `~/.profile` file.

Comment: Putting this into `~/.profile` didn't work for me, but I put

`_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel -Dswing.crossplatformlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel"` 

into `/etc/environment` (note the usage of double rather than single quotes and the missing `export`, otherwise the magic doesn't work).

Comment: Works fine with SweetHome3D and Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. If anyone is experiencing Swing application crash like mine, consider removing the last option `Dswing.crossplatformlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel`

Answer (score 7):

If you are the developer or it's an open source, an alternative way is to change the look and feel of the application. Insert the below code in the `main` method.

```
for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
    if ("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel".equals(info.getClassName())) {   
       javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
       break;
     } 
}
```

[This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) might be also helpful.

Comment: @Jop Are you sure about other platforms? What about KDE themes?

Comment: Nevermind, I was wrong, sorry. But why not just `javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel");`?

Comment: @Jop Since `Java` applications are platform independent you should check if `GTK` theme is installed in your system.