# Bold fonts in muCommander

Tags: java, fonts

I have bold fonts in muCommander everywhere under GTK+ theme.

I have tried changing styles (in app menu) manualy but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Uncommenting the second line here:

```
# uncomment to set the default look and feel to GTK
swing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel
```

in

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/swing.properties
```

solved my problem. Thanks to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/21887/28757) answer to another question. :)