# Creating a Desktop Application for Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, java

I want to create a desktop application and use it on Ubuntu based distributions. I have very good knowledge on Java Desktop Applications. But look and feel of Java Desktop Applications in Linux doesn't look very good.

Is there any other way to get a more better and pleasant look ?

Comment: Did you try use **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2592258/2650174)** statement ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `GTKLookAndFeel`

```
javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel");
```

see the [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21886/how-can-i-get-a-java-apps-to-use-the-gtk-theme).

Comment: Do I need to specify the version of GTK with it.

Comment: No, I don't think there are versions. See [the look and feel tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html). It requires `GTK+ 2.2` or later.