# How to fix Numix theme on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, themes, gtk

I'm using the Numix-bluish-3.16 theme on Ubuntu 14.04. However, the visual experience is not very consistent. Some examples:

[image: Software Center]

[image: Eclipse IDE]

Is it an incompatibility issue with my GTK version?

Comment: How did you isntall the theme?

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:numix/ppa
 `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install numix-gtk-theme

Answer (score 2):

Fry, try to install it from various sources - you probably need to find a gtk3.10 compatible version of the theme (at a guess from the 14.04 [gnome-shell version](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/gnome-shell)):

- The [Numix PPA](https://launchpad.net/~numix/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages) should have a package that works for trusty:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:numix/ppa
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install numix-gtk-theme
  ```
- Or try the zip files from [it's Github page](https://github.com/shimmerproject/Numix) and/or [it's DeviantArt page](http://satya164.deviantart.com/art/Numix-GTK3-theme-360223962), and extract them to `~/.local/share/themes` or `~/.themes` or `/usr/share/themes`.

If you cannot get a working version, you should report it as a bug. This can be done [on it's GitHub page](https://github.com/shimmerproject/Numix/issues) - you need to include your ubuntu version, desktop environment, how you installed it, and the names of applications that have issues (if you are having problems with Java apps, first try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21886/how-can-i-get-a-java-apps-to-use-the-gtk-theme).)