# Repository adding > problem

Tags: apt, updates, ppa, repository, ubuntu-tweak

After running those two commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/next
sudo apt-get update
```

I am getting this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/next/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/next/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/next/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I don't really understand the error in the last few lines.
(Had to remove the http: before the ppa (no more then 2 Links...)

If I dismiss these errors.

The installation of ubuntu-tweak does not work

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

This output:

```
niclas@ThinkPad:~$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
[sudo] password for niclas: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-tweak
```

Would be thankfull for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't succeed to install `Ubuntu tweak` from ppa, you can install it from debian package (`.deb`) following these steps:

1. Download package from [Ubuntu Tweak website](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/).
2. Open terminal and change your working directory where you downloaded the file (e.g Download directory).

   ```
   cd Download
   ```
3. Now you can install `Ubuntu Tweak` with this command:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i <package>
   ```

   (change <package> with `.deb` name, e.g. `ubuntu-tweak_0.8.7-1-trusty2_all.deb`)

---

You can get more info about `dpkg` command reading manual with this command:

```
man dpkg
```

I hope this could help you.

---

**EDIT**:
If your error is caused by some missing packages  you can try to solve it with the following command that will fix package dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

After this you can try to reinstall `Ubuntu-tweak`.

If previous solution doesn't work, it could means that `Ubuntu Tweak` package could be not ready for Ubuntu 16.04, since last update was made two years ago. I didn't find any information about compatibility with Ubuntu 16.04 neither on [ubuntu wiki](http://wiki.ubuntu-it.org/AmministrazioneSistema/UbuntuTweak) nor on [official website](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/about/). Hence I suggest to you to wait for a while and see if it will be released a new version.

Meanwhile you can try to install `unity-tweak-tool`. It is a similar program that let you tweak some aspects of Unity. There isn't an `Apps manager` or `Janitor`, but if you only want to change appearance you can use it. You can install it with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Comment: If I try that I am getting this error in the end: 
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ubuntu-tweak

Comment: Is it possible that ubuntu tweak doesn'w work yet with 16.04?

Comment: @Niclas - that might be it.

Comment: Okay so I am now using unity tweak tool. That one is working fine. ( installed over software center)

Comment: But I still had the problem that some repositorys does not seem to work. Even simple things like themes wouldn't be installed. Might be caused by 16.04 just aswell...

Comment: @Niclas You can try to install `Numix` theme from its `ppa`. Watch the answer of this post http://askubuntu.com/questions/640608/how-to-fix-numix-theme-on-ubuntu-14-04 I am almost sure that works also on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Numix worked but sth like Flatabulous didn't work :S

Answer (score 0):

use this repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
```

Comment: Didn't work still unable to locate package.