# Is there a way to specify a global look and feel for swing apps?

Tags: java, netbeans, ambiance

Every time I install Netbeans on Ubuntu, I have to edit the ./etc/netbeans.conf file to include an option specifying the look and feel; otherwise, the menus are all black on dark gray, which is impossible to use.

Is there a way to specify a global look and feel for swing apps, so that this isn't such a pain? Here is the line I have to change:

```
46: netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true"
```

becomes:

```
46: netbeans_default_options="--laf com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel -J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true"
```

Answer (score 2):

The menus are dark and gray because of a Java bug. You can find it on Ubuntu's bug tracker. In the meantime, if you want to integrate Netbeans in the global menu, there's a way to do that. Here's how it looks like: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8d9szgPhs8

The steps, obtained from [this blog post](http://hanynowsky.wordpress.com/2012/05/12/integration-of-java-swing-applications-with-unity-global-menu-in-ubuntu-12-04/) are as follows.

1. First install `openjdk-7-jdk`. It's required, so if you use 6, be careful.
2. To make Netbeans use `openjdk-7-jdk`, launch Netbeans with

   > /opt/netbeans-7.1.2/bin/netbeans --jdkhome
   >   /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386

   You can make a .desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications` with that as the exec command, for conveience. Copy the default one and edit it.
3. Install and use the **Java Swing Ayatana** plugin from [this googlecode page](http://code.google.com/p/java-swing-ayatana/downloads/list).
4. Restart Netbeans.

Comment: Also, the jdk you use in the Exec might be different for you, because I use the 32 bit version.

Comment: Sweet-- it not easier, but probably worth the effort. It's always annoyed me how java apps don't work with the global menu.